# using conjunctions multiple times in one sentence

Tags: conjunctions

> I love basketball, **and** my brother loves tennis, **but** our sister hates us two loving sports, **so** whenever we try to play sports, she tries to disturb us, **so**, yesterday, we decided to kill our sister so that we can play sports without being bothered by our sister!

I read in an SAT book this isn't grammatically wrong. Can I trust the book?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple conjunctions in one sentence.  Is there a specific reason you think the book might be incorrect?

Comment: Don't confuse written and spoken English. Not the same thing. Your sentence is spoken. Anyway, the end of your sentence does not make sense.

Comment: What doesn't make sense? The brother and 'I' wanted to play sports,so we killed the sister who was continuously disturbing our fun. Is there a problem?

Comment: Stangdon Because it sounds a little weird. I don't just blindly believe in whatever the book says. Funny how I won't even believe an SAT textbook, but that's just how I roll.

Comment: It is a weird, long sentence, which an editor would probably break up with a period rather than a comma after "she tries to disturb us". Besides that, I don't see any obvious grammar error, like subject-verb disagreement. You could argue about whether every comma is needed, but punctuation isn't grammar, so that's not the issue.